# How to measure the time in the awk shell?

Tags: linux, awk, time

I want to use awk to perform batch jobs and calculate the time it takes.

My code looks like this:

```
echo 1 | awk '{system("time pwd")}'
```

But an error occurred: `sh: 1: time:not found`

The type of time() is:

```
type time
```

`time is a shell keyword`

Comment: I guess you can use `/usr/bin/time` instead.

Comment: How accurate should the measurement be? Is the accuracy of one second sufficient?

Comment: The system doesn't have `/usr/bin/time`, and I don't have administrator privileges to install.

Comment: One second is sufficient.

Comment: The typical awk script will take less than a second to run so .... what do you mean by "I want to use awk to perform batch jobs"? It sounds like you might be trying to use awk as a shell and THAT would take a long time to run but is almost certainly the wrong thing to do.

Comment: As Ed implies trying to use awk as a shell itself is likely not what you want.  Awk is not itself a shell (without a big effort)  there is no interactive read evaluate print  loop (REPL).  typically the rough time would be in the same system shell that you are calling awk from.  so `time awk -f script`

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore, I've found other ways to do looping and timing at the same time. Initially, I wanted to use code like this:  `cat list.txt | awk '{system( "time {command} $1")}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job with accuracy of one second and GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{start=systime(); system("sleep 2"); stop=systime(); print stop-start}'
```

Output:

```
2
```